# Problems of GET and POST methods in Python

Tags: python, html

File name **mypage.py**

Python code

```
form = cgi.FieldStorage()

name = form.getfirst('name', 'empty')
id   = form.getfirst('id', 'empty')

print """\
    Content-Type: text/html\n
    <html>
    <body>
        <p>Name: "%s"</p>
        <p>ID: "%s"</p>
    </body>
    </html>
    """ % (name, id)
```

HTML inside the same file

```
<form name="frm" method="post" action="mypage.py?id=33">
<input type="text" name="name" value="MyName" />
<input type="Submit" id="btn" value="Send" />
```

After submitting the form (pressing Send button), I can see this URL with following output

```
  localhost:8000/cgi-bin/mypage.py?id=33

  Name: "empty" 
  ID: "33"
```

if I change the form method POST to GET

```
<form name="frm" method="get" action="mypage.py?id=33">
```

then I can see this URL with following output

```
localhost:8000/cgi-bin/mypage.py?name=MyName 

Name: "MyName"
ID: "empty"
```

I don't understand why I am not receiving text field value with POST method ? And why I am unable to receive id value in query string with GET method ?

Its simple python page without any framework. BTW I am using "python-bugzilla 0.8.0" downloaded from [here](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/python-bugzilla) but i think my given code is just a simple page and has nothing to do with this package.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance,

Comment: You're probably better off using a web framework these days.

Comment: Sure, but for now I am looking some solution to get rid of this problem.

Comment: Just asking, with the get method are you filling the form or leaving it empty.

Comment: Thanks for asking, yes I am filling the form in both cases. Actually its filled automatically. If you see this value="MyName".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for the help.

problem was here.

```
form = cgi.FieldStorage()
```

As I've mentioned in comments of your answers that I've printed "form" and here is output: "FieldStorage(None, None, [])".

So, if FieldStorage doesn't have any value then it doesn't matter which function is being used to get the form value. But it was really good information and practical as well.

previously `form = cgi.FieldStorage()` was declared inside another function which was wrong, that's why FieldStorage was empty.

Here is WRONG code.

```
def myfunction ():
    cgitb.enable()
    form = cgi.FieldStorage()
```

---

**Solution 1:**

`form = cgi.FieldStorage()` shall define inside the run() function and pass this form as parameter of other function to get values of form.
i.e.

```
def run():
    cgitb.enable()
    form = cgi.FieldStorage()
    myfunction(form)
```

Now its working

```
def myfunction (form):
    name = form.getfirst('name', 'empty')
    id   = form.getfirst('id', 'empty')
```

---

**Solution 2:**

`form = cgi.FieldStorage()` shall define directly inside the main function then don't need to pass it as parameter .
i.e.

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    cgitb.enable()
    form = cgi.FieldStorage()
```

Now its working too and form is accessible inside the myfunction.

```
def myfunction ():
    name = form.getfirst('name', 'empty')
    id   = form.getfirst('id', 'empty')
```

---

Thanks everybody.

Answer (score 1):

Your GET is proper:

```
<form name="frm" method="get" action="mypage.py?id=33">
```

But your POST is not:

```
<form name="frm" method="post" action="mypage.py?id=33">
```

You can't add a GET style variable (?id=33) to the action of your POST. It should be:

```
<form name="frm" method="post" action="mypage.py">
<input type="hidden" name="id" value="33">
```

[See HTTP Methods: GET vs. POST](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_httpmethods.asp): "Query strings (name/value pairs) are sent in the URL of a GET request" and "Query strings (name/value pairs) are sent in the HTTP message body of a POST request".

Not adhering to these rules would cause unexpected results such as you are seeing.

Comment: Thanks Matt: Its not working at all for POST method. But its working well for GET method where I can see all the values in URL (not good). 

So problem is POST method. I've printed cgi.FieldStorage() and here is output:  "FieldStorage(None, None, [])" 

any idea ?

Comment: Yeah, I think the reason @skolima and I both jumped on the misuse of POST and GET is that it's hard to debug problems when the standards aren't obeyed. Would you change the code so it properly uses POST and GET per my description above and just see what happens? I've added a second answer.

Answer (score 1):

Technically, a `POST` target url should not have `GET` parameters, so the `?id=33` in the target is invalid. I'm also guessing that it's confusing to the `FieldStorage` module, that might be why you are getting unexpected results.

Comment: Thanks skolima: Its not working at all for POST method. But its fine for GET method where I can see values of form fields in URL (not good). 

So problem is POST method. I've printed cgi.FieldStorage() and here is output:  "FieldStorage(None, None, [])" 

any idea ?

Answer (score 1):

You should properly use POST and GET per my other answer. That said, I'm worried about your use of form.getfirst and variable names.

Per [the documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/library/cgi.html):

FieldStorage.getfirst(name[, default]) - This method **always returns only one value associated with form field name**. The method returns **only the first value in case that more values were posted under such name**.

You've named your name variable name which is a silly name. See, lots of names. And your form has a name. And it's a field. Same with ID. You should change your variable names as such:

```
<form name="MyForm" method="post" action="mypage.py">
<input type="text" name="FullName" value="MyName" />
<input type="text" name="FormID" value="33" />
<input type="Submit" id="btn" value="Send" />
```

and change your Python as follows:

```
form = cgi.FieldStorage()

FullName = form.getfirst('FullName', 'empty')
FormID   = form.getfirst('FormID', 'empty')

print """\
    Content-Type: text/html\n
    <html>
    <body>
        <p>Name: "%s"</p>
        <p>ID: "%s"</p>
    </body>
    </html>
    """ % (FullName, FormID)
```

That's the code for a proper POST and printing of the variables. Does it work?